# How do I get the client id for the ISubscriber connection?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using the StackExchange.Redis NuGet package.

I would like to get the Client ID for the connection that is created when I call `redis.GetSubscriber()`.  This method returns an object of type `ISubscriber` and creates a new connection to the redis server.

I can't find any properties or methods on this object that provides access to the client id of the connection it uses.

I know I can send the `CLIENT ID` command to redis, but this doesn't help as there doesn't appear to be a way to send this command manually via the `ISubscriber` object or via any of the objects accessible from it's methods and properties.

I know I can call `redis.GetDatabase()` and then run `db.Execute("CLIENT", "ID")`, but `GetDatabase()` creates a new connection, and the client id that is returned isn't the one being used by the `ISubscriber` object.

```
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379");

// This returns an ISubscriber object and creates a new connection
var subscriber = redis.GetSubscriber(); // I want the client id for this connection

// This returns an IDatabase object and also creates a new connection
var db = redis .GetDatabase();
var dbClientId = invalidatorDb.Execute("CLIENT", "ID"); // not the client id I want
```

Is anyone able to offer some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very interesting question; in particular:

1. the `CLIENT ID` operation only exists from Redis 5.0 onwards
2. the `CLIENT ID` operation *cannot* be performed once the connection is in subscriber mode

To see the latter, consider the following trace (with my comments after `#`)

```
> ping # check connection
< +PONG

> client id # check can get client id on vanilla connection
< :5

> subscribe foo # switch to subscriber mode
< *3
< $9
< subscribe
< $3
< foo
< :1

> client id # check can get client id on subscriber connection
< -ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / PING / QUIT allowed in this context
```

This means that to get the `CLIENT ID` of a subscriber connection, we'd need to change the library to issue that command much earlier in the pipe than you have access to, before it becomes a subscriber. Effectively, we'd need to issue a speculative `CLIENT ID` *just in case we need it later* as part of the connection handshake. I'm not against this - it is cheap enough, and we could easily do it for all connections; but: it *does* require library changes.

I'm *guessing* this is because you're trying to implement `CLIENT TRACKING` with the `REDIRECT` option, as there aren't *that many* alternative uses for a subscriber client id.

Note: you *could* try and guess with `CLIENT LIST`, but I do not recommend this.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. Yes it’s for client tracking. Ok so I understand the problem now. Could I potentially subclass some of those objects and override some methods to get access to the internals before the SUBBSCRIBE command is run? Alternatively, I could manually track the ids I do know about in redis then loop through the remaining ids in code to test which one redirects to my subscriber. Brute force.

Comment: "no" to the first, "I don't recommend it" to the second

Comment: In regards to future code changes, wouldn’t necessarily need to get client Id for all connections, but it would be nice to have a method to hook into the creation process and related objects.

Comment: That’s a bummer